# cx_oracle connection without DSN

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I am maintaining some code where i came about a curious connection string of following type to an oracle database (from redhat linux):

```
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.Connection("username/password")
```

Notably no DSN is specified; User name and password are enough (the connection is working).

How is this possible? How does cx_oracle know where to connect to? Is there some default value/environment variable that is used if no DSN is given? The way I understood the documentation, the DSN is a mandatory argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Devyl mentioned, if you have ORACLE_SID or TWO_TASK environment variables set, they maybe used to make a connection.

E.g. see this answer https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:89412348059

Comment: On Windows, the equivalent environment variable is 'LOCAL'.  To use any of these, Python cx_Oracle must be using the same libraries that the database is using.  You then get what is technically called a 'bequeath' connection.  If Python cx_Oracle is using a different set of libraries, eg from Instant Client, then would always need to specify a connection string in the `Connection()` call.

Answer (score 0):

cx_oracle has method to create dsn [makedsn](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.makedsn)

```py
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid=None, service_name=None, region=None, sharding_key=None, super_sharding_key=None)

with cx_Oracle.connect(user=user, password=password,
                       dsn=dsn,
                       encoding="UTF-8") as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into SomeTable values (:1, :2)",
                   (1, "Some string"))
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Ty, but i dont see how this is relevant. The very point of my question is that the code im reviewing is not calling makedsn, neither explicit nor implicit in the connection string, yet is somehow working.

Comment: do you have an environment variable `os.environ["ORACLE_SID"]` ?